# Check if the API is reachable

Tags: javascript

What is the best way to tell if the API is online?
I know I can check if the user has the Internet connection using `navigator.onLine` but how about the API?

Should I send a request to some simple endpoint and see if the data goes back to me?

Comment: Absolutely. There is no other way that you can check it. Make a call and check the [**status**](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html )of it.

Comment: Try to use an ajax request using GET method.
A 404 status code is the best sign that the server has not found anything matching the URI given, which means the api is not reachable at least in that endpoint.

Answer (score 4):

I would just simple do a simple "ping" type test, if your API was `https://api.example.com/auth/user` I would just do a simple GET request on `https://api.example.com` if this returns the expected result you can assume the API is online.  This isn't the best test because there still could be a problem with the API but the concept of it being on line is still checked.

If the service you are using has a status page 9/10 the API will be on there. You could use this page to your advantage by scraping the page and checking the status of the API. Say your using the Bitbucket API you could GET this page status.bitbucket.org and then check that the API state is `OPERATIONAL`.

Comment: "Just do a simple GET request on https://api.example.com". How should this return the (which) expected result? Normally the base address is not a valid endpoint which implements a Http GET.

Answer (score 0):

Try this under try catch block and log error or do continue rest of the code based on that

```
try {
   //api request 
} catch (e)
   // log error
   // Set flag
}
```

Based on the flag, do you next action item